# Using a VM for testing, how to artifically reduce performance?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-server, testing

My workstation has VMWare Server, and I'm running a few VMs for mocked production environments.

I'd like to artificially slow them down, which should make finding poorly-performing code easier.  While only having 4GB of RAM on my Win7 box, juggling VMWare + VS2010 does a good enough job so far of slowing things down :|, is there anything else I can do specifically to reduce the performance to maybe the equivalent of a dual 900MHz CPU and 128kbit ISDN line?

Comment: I tried using host.cpukHz, and that had no impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

[WANem](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wanem/) can slow down your network traffic, either as a virtual appliance or a bootable CD on a separate machine.